# Radial component of velocity in a Rankine-vortex

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, velocity

A [Rankine vortex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_vortex) is a model of a vortex that assumes an inner region ($r<R$) with constant vorticity, $\omega_0$, which rotates as a rigid solid, and an outer region ($r>R$) with zero vorticity, $\omega = 0$, which behaves as an irrotational flow.

I'm trying to derive the velocity field of this model in two dimensions through the expression of the vorticity in plane polar coordinates,

$$
\omega=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r v_{\theta}\right)-\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial v_{r}}{\partial \theta}
$$

I have seen that the radial component of the velocity field in this model is zero: $v_r=0$. Is this part of the definition of the model or a consequence of its postulates about the vorticity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I'd say it is just defined by the velocity field $\boldsymbol{v}$, but even so you can derive it if you are willing to accept that it is cylindrically symmetric.

Cylindrical symmetry means that $\boldsymbol{v}$ must be independent of $\theta$ which gives
$$\omega=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r v_{\theta}\right).$$
In the inner region, $\omega=\omega_0$ and so we need
$$v_{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}\omega_0r+\frac{C}{r}$$
where $C$ is a constant. However, the velocity must be finite as $r\rightarrow 0$ and so $C=0$. In the outer region, $\omega=0$ which gives $v_{\theta}\propto{1/r}$.

Now we just need to argue that $v_r$ is zero. We can do this by mass conservation. The mass flux through a cylinder of unit length and radius $r$ is $F=2\pi r v_r$ where we have used that $v_r$ is independent of $\theta$. $F$ must be the same for all $r$, so by considering $r\rightarrow0$ with $v_r$ finite, we see that $F=0$ and so $v_r=0$ for all $r$.